# Python: latex not recognized

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to create a plot in matplotlib where all the labels are in [LaTeX](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html). I am using Jupyter Notebook on Fedora 36 and installed LaTeX using `!pip install latex`. Here is my program:

```
# importing the required module 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    
# x axis values 
x = [1,2,3] 
# corresponding y axis values 
y = [2,4,1] 
    
# plotting the points  
plt.plot(x, y) 
    
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
    
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('My first graph!') 

plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "monospace"})
    
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

Yet, I receive this error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `pip` only installs python libraries.  You likely need to install tex using fedora's package manager: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199638/how-to-fully-install-latex-in-fedora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib` doesn't have a dependency on the python library `latex`; rather, it has a dependency on LaTeX iself. You need to install LaTeX, see [Latex :: Fedora Docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/neurofedora/latex/). Since you only want this for rendering `matplotlib` labels, try this:

```bash
sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-basic
```

If that's not enough, you could install `texlive-scheme-medium` or `texlive-scheme-full`.